# creating a list (max values are given) with all combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm currently working on the K2 Algorithm, where it is necessary to find out all combinations of states and values of the current variable and its possible parents.

e.g. X1, X2 and X3 (current variable) is given. X1 can have the value {0, 1, 2, 3}, X2 {0, 1} and X3 {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

so basically you can create a list with the possible max values: `[3, 1, 4]`

Now where I'm stuck is to create a function that returns all possible combinations:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 0]
...
```

The max values and the length of the list should be flexible.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Tricky problem. Are the inputs always numeric or can they be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a recursive function . I think the code is pretty self explanatory .

```
l=[1, 3, 5, 2]
st=[]
def foo(index,l):
    if(index<len(l)):
        for i in range(l[index]+1):
            st.append(i)
            foo(index+1,l)
            st.pop()
    else:
            print(st)    
foo(0,l)
```

OUTPUT

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
.....
[1, 3, 5, 0]
[1, 3, 5, 1]
[1, 3, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another recursive implementation:

```
def count(maxValsArr):
    # Base case: count all numbers for the last digit
    if len(maxValsArr) == 1:
        return [[x] for x in range(maxValsArr[0] + 1)]

    # Count all numbers from the current digit by incrementing this digit
    # and recursively incrementing later digits
    rtn = []
    for digitVal in range(maxValsArr[0] + 1):
        numbersToRight = count(maxValsArr[1:])
        numbers = [[digitVal] + x for x in numbersToRight]
        rtn = rtn + numbers
    return rtn
```

Output for `count([1, 1, 1])` is `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]`.